# Getting fields of derived class

Tags: python, inheritance

In Python, I can get a classes fields with `__dict__`. Here I have two questions:

Is there a better way to get fields? Because it only brings fields that has values.
How can I get fields that exist only in class itself, not the base class?

Comment: I guess you mean attributes.  Did you try *class-name.attribute-name*?

Comment: Yes, attributes. I'm a python noob, not into terms really. My aim is to make a code generator like thing. I have classes that inherit from another class. I need their attributes and values, not the base classes attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
from types import FunctionType

class A (object):
    def test(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def test12(self):
        pass


print([x for x,y in A.__dict__.items() if type(y) == FunctionType])

print([x for x,y in B.__dict__.items() if type(y) == FunctionType])
```

For attributes which are not methods, try this:

```
attributes = [x for x,y in B.__dict__.items() if (type(y) != FunctionType and type != callable)]

[a for a in attributes if not(a.startswith('__') and a.endswith('__'))]
```

Comment: this code lists the functions. i need attributes. thanks anyway.

Comment: It's pretty much same thing tho.

Comment: Nidhin,  what were you using in your example?  i saw this in a training video or something like it and wanted to experiment.

Comment: yes it gets only the function. Its a list comprehension where-in it get the class' __dict__ items and check whether each of its type is 'function'.

Comment: I have edited to get the attributes. Will that get the intended result?

Comment: A method *is* an attribute!

Comment: Yes it is. So the attributes which are not methods. # Edited the text. Thanks

Comment: See also the `inspect` module in the standard library.

Comment: Nidhin, with a little edit(i edited your code too) it helped me. Thanks a lot.